# Curly braces in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, dictionary, curly-braces

I was working on some SQL (PostgresSQL to be precise) related task and I came across this one particular table. There is a column in it which looks like a Python dictionary.

| ColumnName1 | ColumnName2 |
| --- | --- |
| ABCD | ['{id=1234 , name = "xyz", values = {parameter1 = 47, parameter2 = 89}}'] |
| EFGH | ['{id=5678 , name = "qwe", values = {parameter1 = 34, parameter3 = 475}}'] |

How do I query this "ColumnName2"? How do I filter/aggregate based on "parameter1"? ('Parameter1' is inside a python-dictionary like structure under 'CloumnName2', as shown in the table here)

I appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You could run `SELECT pg_typeof(columnname2) from table_name` to know the column's type. If it's one of json/jsonb there are [some operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) to work with that. The `hstore`  type has [some](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/hstore.html#id-1.11.7.25.6) too. If it's a `varchar` column, it might/will be much harder to work with.

Comment: This is neither valid JSON, nor a hstore value. It looks like some custom format stored in a `varchar` or `text` column (so there is no built-in support from Postgres)

Answer (score 0):

if column is a json type,there are operators available in postgres.
If its varchar, use a python udf to extract out your parameter from column.
You could create function like pythonudf(ColumnName2,'parameter1') and it will return you the data.
Or perhaps reprocess the table and bring it in json column format.